# Duda: Throw Exception o RETURN valor?

Tags: php, excepciones

No sé si alguien mas tendrá ésta duda. La cuestión es que nunca estoy seguro de cuándo conviene lanzar una excepción o usar return. Por ejemplo, tengo este método que valida un string conforme a un patrón REGEX:

```
function string($dato="", $min=0, $max=0, $acentuados=true, $simbolos=true) {
    $dato = trim($dato."");

    if (!is_int($min)) return 1000;
    if ($min < 0) return 1001;

    // resto del código
}
```

Este método podría reescribirlo así y usarlo en un `try..catch`:

```
function string($dato="", $min=0, $max=0, $acentuados=true, $simbolos=true) {
    $dato = trim($dato."");

    if (!is_int($min)) throw new Exception("", 1000); // ya tengo mi array con los mensajes
    if ($min < 0) throw new Exception("", 1001);

    // resto del código
}
```

¿Cuál de las dos formas es la correcta en este caso?

Comment: Una excepcion es algo que no puedes controlar... aca, estas controlando perfectamente lo que pasa, porque querrias mandar una excepcion? podrias devolver un objeto con esa data si quisieras... que tirara un codigo de error y un mensaje si hay un error, o los datos si no ocurrio ningun error...

Comment: Depende... si no ocurre error ¿que regresa?. Si regresa un valor le complicas al cliente al obligarlo a discernir entre un valor y un código de error. Si regresa un booleano lo más lógico sería que al ocurrir un error regrese el booleano opuesto. Considera que hoy no sabes quién utilizará tu función mañana ¿serás tú mismo?. Cuando usas una nueva librería o API prácticamente no te escapas de -por lo menos- darle un vistazo a la documentación ¿Qué te ha sido más fácil implementar?¿con excepciones o con códigos de error?.

Comment: @gbianchi: Irónicamente el [*Manejo de Excepciones*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manejo_de_excepciones) es precisamente para **controlar** errores.

Comment: @Sal Exactamente, las excepciones se diseñaron para decirle al usuario del código que algo salió mal y proporcionarle detalles sobre lo ocurrido.

Comment: @Sal Las funciones de validación gralmente devuelven `bool true` o `bool false` y en caso de error un `integer`. Estoy tratando de estandarizar el código y comprender por qué me conviene usar excepciones. Y no veo la diferencia si de todas maneras voy a validar los datos en la función/método y el error/excepción va a pasar por `class Error` en donde manejo los mensajes que se muestran...

Comment: ninguna... de las dos ... esta desaconejado retornar datos cuando recibes algo no esperado ... y tambiene sta desaconcejado usar excepciones durante la comprobacion de datos.

Comment: en su lugar deberias implementar tipado fuerte y pruebas unitarias. garantiza tu desarrollo.

Answer (score 3):

Basaré mi respuesta en [Why is it better to throw an exception rather than return an error code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4670987/why-is-it-better-to-throw-an-exception-rather-than-return-an-error-code)

> ¿Porqué es mejor lanzar una excepción en lugar de devolver un código de error?

---

Las excepciones se diseñaron para decirle al usuario del código que algo salió mal, dónde salió mal y proporcionar detalles sobre lo ocurrido.

En cambio, un código de error devuelto no proporciona esta información y obliga a quienes no escribieron la función a entrar al cuerpo de la misma y ver cómo está hecha.

Para explicarlo mejor, propondré un ejemplo en el que yo estuviese escribiendo una función `IndexOf(string)` en C#:

```
public int IndexOf(string value)
{
    if (value == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(value));
    }

    // Implementación
}
```

Si ahora, invoco esta función de esta forma:

```
string str  = "Hola Mundo";
int indice  = str.IndexOf(null);
HacerAlgo(indice);
```

Obtengo el siguiente error:

```
Seguimiento de pila:
    En el archivo String.cs:
        Ha ocurrido una NullReferenceException en la línea 25 : El parámetro `value` no
        puede ser nulo.
```

<sup>¿Es esto lo suficientemente claro?</sup>

La ejecución el código se detiene, no alcanza la función `HacerAlgo` y me obliga a revisar qué salió mal si quiero que mi programa funcione.

Veamos ahora qué hace la implementación que devuelve un código error:

```
public int IndexOf(string value)
{
    if (value == null)
    {
        return -1;
    }

    // Implementación
}
```

Si ahora, invoco esta función de esta forma:

```
string str  = "Hola Mundo";
int indice  = str.IndexOf(null);
HacerAlgo(indice);
```

Se pasará el valor `-1` a mi función `HacerAlgo` y...

- ¿Está preparada esta función para manejar este valor?
- ¿Puedo asegurar que cada función esté preparada para saber qué hacer con este valor?
- Inclusive, ¿Funciones de terceros de las que no tengo el control?
- Otros programadores, o yo mismo en algún tiempo, ¿Sabremos qué ocurre en caso de un valor incorrecto? ¿en especial, si mi función no maneja correctamente cada caso de error?

Parecerá que mi código se ejecuta correctamente, pero está pasando el valor incorrecto y es más tedioso capturar este tipo de errores.

---

**Recuerda:**

- Una devolución de valor incorrecto es propensa a ser ignorada por los programadores. Una excepción no puede ser ignorada.
- Usa devoluciones de valores solo si sabes cómo manejarlos, si conoces qué hacer con cada valor devuelto.
- Si tu función no maneja los códigos de devolución de error, es posible que nada lo haga.
- Una excepción te dice dónde y porqué ocurrió el error sin que tú tengas que proporcionarle un mensaje, que es opcional. Un valor devuelto casi siempre te obliga a proporcionar un mensaje y asegurarte de tomar en cuenta cada posible caso.

---

Un valor de retorno es mejor opción que una excepción en casos específicos:

Retomemos mi función `IndexOf`, acá quiero que la ejecución del código se detenga si, por ejemplo, le proporciono un valor `null`, ya que `null` representa un valor inexistente y no puedes buscar algo que no existe.

En cambio, algo diferente es cuando le proporciono una cadena válida y no la encuentra, en este caso no me conviene que pare la ejecución a causa de una excepción, sino que me indique con un valor devuelto que no hubo coincidencias, y de esta forma, ser yo quien decida qué hacer, por ejemplo, que me devuelva `-1`.

Lo mismo si estoy escribiendo un API, espero que el API envíe al cliente un código de error, ya que si lanza una excepción, sería en el servidor, nunca llegaría al cliente y por ende, nunca sabría que salió mal.

Comment: Entiendo tu respuesta. SIn embargo, cuando vamos a usar una función, la que sea, incluso las nativas del lenguaje, lees la documentación. En la documentación te dice cómo se usa y cuáles son los valores devueltos. También se supone que uno valida los datos antes de procesarlos. Y el uso que se le de al valor retornado dependerá del programador que también contemplará qué hacer con ese valor a continuación.

Comment: Una solución que se me ocurre es definir una constante `DEFINE('USAR_EXCEPCIONES', TRUE, TRUE);` y con un `if (!is_int($min)) { if (USAR_EXCEPCIONES) throw new Exception("", 1000); return 1000; }` dejar que sea el programador el que decida...

Comment: @julio Bueno, los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas, por lo que me limitaré a comentarte lo siguiente: Te estás basando en suposiciones, supones que debe ser así, pero en las aplicaciones en producción en el mundo real no lo es. ¿Has visto otros proyectos? ¿Has visto que lo común sea devolver un código de error?

Comment: Cómo?? Para nada. Valido todos los datos en la función y devuelvo un código de error/éxito. No estoy asumiendo nada. Si el parámetro debe ser un `integer` y no lo es devuelvo un error. Si lo es pero no está dentro del rango, devuelvo otro error. Y así. Al igual que con un error se puede omitir su tratamiento, una excepción también puede ser ignorada dejando el `catch` vacío... depende del programador. `preg_match()`, por ejemplo, devuelve `false`, `1` o `0`.. puedo elegir no verificar el resultado y que sea lo que dior quiera... o sea, en este caso, no veo una diferencia significativa.

Comment: La proposición de tu segundo comentario es algo muy específico de vos, ya que por lo general, cuando cambias a un entorno de producción, las excepciones se apagan. Aunque no significan que el usuario no vea una si sucede algo que rompe tu app.

Comment: @julio Si te acomoda emplear un valor de retorno en vez de excepciones, eres libre de hacerlo en tu proyecto y estandarizarlo en tu código. Yo solo te he comentado lo que se usa en las aplicaciones del mundo. Rara vez ves un código de error en vez de una excepción. Pero por favor, no me creas a mí, te aconsejo que profundices un poco más tu investigación viendo códigos fuentes de otros proyectos o que preguntes a más programadores. No obstante, usa la forma que te acomode, y si deseas trabajar en grupo, explícales a los miembros qué es cada error mediante comentarios o documentación. Saludos.

Comment: O sea que mi punto es válido. No hay diferencia significativa y mas teniendo en cuenta "cuando cambias a un entorno de producción, las excepciones se apagan" tiene mas sentido usar un `return`. Una función correctamente documentada para un programador responsable debería ser suficiente para escribir un código que no se rompa. Gracias por la info y por el tiempo!

Comment: @julio No se apagan del todo, están ahí y pueden ser lanzadas en cualquier momento, sea en producción o no. Pero explicarlo se hace demasiado amplio, mejor que lo investigues. Además, si desde el principio has insistido en emplear `return` e insistes en que es mejor que una excepción, no entiendo porqué consultaste la opinión de los demás.

Comment: Siempre leo la doc oficial, otros sitios incluído éste, hago pruebas y cuando no lo consigo vengo a preguntar ya sea a arreglar un código o sacarme una duda específica como esta y acá hay gente que sabe mas y tiene mas experiencia y así he mejorado mucho. Lo puedo hacer de ambas formas. Aunque me mantengo con el `return` porque es mas "directo" y como dijiste y tmb leí "dejo que el programador decida que hacer a continuación". `try...catch` lo veo mas para una consulta a una bbdd, por ejemplo. Te agradezco nuevamente porque si que entendí mucho mejor el tema.